# How to join these two tables?

Tags: mysql, select

I have:

```
TABLE: USERS
UID | NAME
1   | Bob
2   | John
```

And I have:

```
TABLE: HITS
HITID | UID
1     | 1
2     | 2
3     | 2
4     | 1
5     | 2
6     | 2
```

I want:

```
UID | HITS
1   | 2
2   | 4
```

Seems simple enough, but I can't seem to do it?

Comment: What are 2 and 4 in the result table HITS Colums ?? are they no of hits? from HITID ??

Comment: JOIN: `select u.name as name, h.hitid from users u inner join hits h on u.uid = h.uid`; COUNT: `select uid, count(hitid) from hits group by uid`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT UID, COUNT(UID) HITS FROM HITS 
GROUP BY UID;
```

Comment: Your absolutely right. There's no reason to join the tables in the example. What if I add a column called "name" in the uid folder?

Comment: Explain your question with example that what you really want to do. Where you want to add column and from where you can fetch data of that column

Comment: @RD: Q: What if the dinosaurs never became extinct?  Would we all fly pterodactyls instead of having invented airplanes?  Q: You realize Saharsh Shah gave you exactly the correct answer to your original question, don't you?

Comment: @paulsm4 ask this question to RD not me

Answer (score 2):

This Might help you

```
DECLARE @USERS TABLE(UID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @USERS (UID,NAME) VALUES ('1','Bob'),('2','John')

DECLARE @HITS TABLE(HITID INT,UID INT)
INSERT INTO @HITS (HITID,UID) VALUES('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','2'),('4','1'),('5','2'),('6','2')
```

Use JOIN if you want to use Both USERS Table and HITS Table

```
SELECT U.UID,COUNT(H.HITID) AS HITS FROM @USERS AS U INNER JOIN @HITS AS H ON U.UID = H.UID GROUP BY U.UID
```

OR Use Simple Query If you want to use only HITS Table

```
SELECT UID, COUNT(UID) HITS FROM @HITS GROUP BY UID
```

I also Created Temp tables in this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.UID, COUNT(b.UID) HITS FROM HITS a, USERS b
WHERE a.UID=b.UID
GROUP BY UID
```

This should work

Comment: The *real* Sheldon Cooper would never give such a silly answer :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I am actually trying to behave like how normal average IQ people would be.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick

```
SELECT H.UID, COUNT(*) AS 'HITS'
FROM HITS H
GROUP BY H.UID
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the name of the users, then you need to join it

```
SELECT  a.Name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN HITS b
            ON a.UID = b.UID
GROUP BY a.UID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94bd/1)